# Very simple PHP Quiz for Practice ( IF ELSEIF ELSE Condition ) not working properly

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to teach my self PHP and for practice I decided to create a simple quiz. The radio button options are valued as integers 0 through 2 depending on the question.

The PHP script simply pulls the value from the form adds them and stores data in **$sum**
A message should appear on three possible conditions. The last condition is not rendering properly.
Here is the [link](http://promarketme.com/test/quiz.php) to show that it is storing the value of **$sum**

```
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $one = ($_POST["one"]);
  $two = ($_POST["two"]);
  $three = ($_POST["three"]);
  $four = ($_POST["four"]);
  $five = ($_POST["five"]);

    $sum = $one + $two + $three + $four + $five;


if ($sum <= 2){
$answer = "Sorry you are not cut out to run your own business!!";
}
elseif ($sum > 2 && $sum <= 4){
$answer = "You are a hustler by nature";
}
elseif ($sum > 4 && $sum <= 7){
$answer = "You are a tycoonist, that will take over the world";
}
else { 
$answer = "";
}
```

Comment: With proper indenting, errors like this one will be easier to find.

Comment: Please post the full code

Comment: Thank you for all the fast responses I did fix it already I missed the first '}' closing bracket within the if (SERVER_REQUEST) block... Sorry for the ugly code was just a quick write up in dreamweaver was just trying to work on my PHP logic and syntax... Such a stupid mistake but thank you

Answer (score 3):

you're missing a { in the line:

```
elseif ($sum > 2 && $sum <= 4)
```

Comment: thank you so much that was such a horrible noob mistake especially since its not the first language I know i guess thats an obvious sign its time to go to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the bracket after `elseif ($sum > 2 && $sum <= 4)`. Use the code below

```
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $one = ($_POST["one"]);
  $two = ($_POST["two"]);
  $three = ($_POST["three"]);
  $four = ($_POST["four"]);
  $five = ($_POST["five"]);

    $sum = $one + $two + $three + $four + $five;


if ($sum <= 2){
$answer = "Sorry you are not cut out to run your own business!!";
}
elseif ($sum > 2 && $sum <= 4){
$answer = "You are a hustler by nature";
}
elseif ($sum > 4 && $sum <= 7){
$answer = "You are a tycoonist, that will take over the world";
}
else { 
$answer = "";
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I think the original question is missing code. It starts a if statement at the very beginning but has no closing bracket - so we need to see his full source to fully identify what the problem is.

Comment: @PressingOnAlways By the way +1 for you answer

Comment: I actually did have that bracket closed within my original script but did miss it rewriting the code on here :X, Although, the problem is solved. Which was the first if statement bracket missing for the REQUEST_METHOD .. Angry about the amateur move but, Thank you for the feed back!